# Необходима помощь с HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать этот текст, используя только html/css
Именно в таком порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

требуется так раскидать буквы?
тогда надо для каждой буквы создать свой контейнер `<div></div>` и работать со свойствами

```
position: absolute;
left: /*значение*/;
top: /*значение*/;
```

если же надо, чтобы буквы были в случайных положениях - то тут без Javascript не обойтись

Например,

```css
.block {
    position:   relative;
    
    width:      400px;
    height:     200px;
    
    border:     1px solid red;
}

.letter1 {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       10px;
    top:        100px;
}

.letter2 {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       50px;
    top:        20px;
}

.letter3 {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       60px;
    top:        -30px;
}

.letter4 {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       110px;
    top:        150px;
}

.letter5 {
    position:   absolute;
    left:       200px;
    top:        220px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'block'>
    <div class = 'letter1'>H</div>
    <div class = 'letter2'>E</div>
    <div class = 'letter3'>L</div>
    <div class = 'letter4'>L</div>
    <div class = 'letter5'>O</div>
</div>
```

поэтому уточните задачу